# Wiring AC condenser to Furnace

Tags: wiring, hvac, furnace

[image]

Hello
So this is what I was left with
I am trying to tie in fan on/off and a AC condenser 
I have 2 wires for my limit switch, 2 wires from my 24ac transformer, 2 wires from my AC condenser and 2 from my gas/heat and then a 5 wire to my thermostat 
There is no control board at all 
How would I go about wiring this and getting the AC and fan control on/off working

I have a Goodman VSX130241AA condenser. The original thermostat only had 2 wires connected to it white (heat) and red I would assume power that’s it so I got a Honeywell TH9302 WiFi. I did run a new 5 wire for the new thermostat as the old one was only a 22/2 awg.

Thank You in Advance
Scott

Comment: Find and install the appropriate control board? This doesn't look like a complete system ready to be controlled by a thermostat unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

To long for a comment, not a proper answer but it may assist the OP in getting it connected or provide us with enough information to help out.

First we would need the model number of the condenser or outside unit (do you have power wired to the contactor?) next we would need the model of the thermostat (the thermostat turns the fan on in the air handler with heat, cool & fan modes) last we would need to know if the contactor control is wired to the thermostat. Notice I keep going back to the thermostat. To me this looks like an add on so you will have to have a thermostat that can control 3 things. #1 is the fan, number 2 is heat and number 3 is cool. This can be done with the right thermostat. However the outside unit requires power. Most of the time 240v and depending on the size of the unit it will need a 20-50 amp circuit with a local disconnect outside within site of the condenser. The common and cool wires going to outside unit or condenser, the heat and fan should be the same as it originally was but you might need to separate the call for heat and fan signals coming from the thermostat. It sounds like you have enough wires we just need the model numbers so we can help with more than guessing at the standard color codes for the wiring.

Comment: Thanks Ed so I have a Goodman VSX130241AA condenser wired with 220v and local disconnect also have the Blue& Yellow low voltage wires from condenser to the furnace The new Thermostat is a Honeywell TH9302 WiFi , the original thermostat only had 2 wires connected to it white (heat) and red I would assume power that’s it. I did run a new 5 wire for the new thermostat as the old one was only a 22/2 awg. I verified power at condenser as well as 24v inside the furnace I don’t see and can relay wires in condenser though all I have is the 2 black wires from my fan limit switch TY

Comment: There should be a contactor or electrical relay in the condescending or out door unit, this is controlled by the cooling output of the thermostat between that and the C wire (your blue and yellow) you will need the c wire at the furnace and air handler with the fan and heat wires this is where some mods Are needed so we can turn on only the fan what is the model # of your heater & air handler it sounds like the outside unit is setup if 24v applied to the blue yellow and the condenser starts we just need to figure out the heat fan separation. It can be done using the stat and relays if needed

Comment: @ac repair service Dallas Tx in what way is this comment helpful? Many people have systems that are similar to the op. The op was not asking about efficiency